# Regex to match until either including or not including

Tags: javascript, regex, match, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking for a Regex to find a substring starting at `A`, stopping at either `B` or `C`. However, when it's `B`, it shouldn't include the `B`, but when it's `C`, it should include the `C`.

For example this text: `XXAXXXXBXX`, then it should return `AXXXX` but when it's `XXAXXXXCXX` it should return `AXXXXC`.

I already looked at positive lookahead and stuff, but it doesn't work so far. Currently I'm using something like `A.+(?=C|B)` but obviously that's not right :( Anyone an idea?

Comment: You do not seem to need any lookarounds here, unless you have oversimplified the sample text/expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found already the answer! I can use something like this: `(A.+)((?=B)|C)` which starts with `A.+` and matches until either C or the lookahead B (which doesn't include B at all).

Comment: There is also `/A([^B]*|C)/` which doesn't use any lookahead. In''XXACBCXX'' your pattern will match "'ACBC" which I think you do not want. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `A[^BC]+C?`.

Explanation: it starts match with `A`, then it matches one or more characters other than `B` or `C` (`[^BC]+`), after that, it matches at most one `C`, if it's not present, then don't match anything else.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TyZxda/1)